# Pool Pump not working, gives overcurrent error, no sound whatsoever

Tags: pump, pool

Our pool pump stopped working about a week ago. Inspecting it more closely, it's an "[Intelliflo 4 160](https://www.poolexpress.com/pentair-intelliflo-pump-4x160-vs-3050-variable-speed-011013)". It has a small control panel with some LED's - when I press the "start" button, the red alarm button blinks continuously and the green power LED blinks in sets of eight blinks. According to the [manual](http://cdn.lesliespool.com/wpdf/intellipro-manual.pdf), this indicates "Over current alarm", with the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Examine fluid/mechanical system for source of overload.
2. De-energize motor and determine if motor spins freely.
3. Replace drive.

Given that the motor makes absolutely no sound at all (it doesn't seem to even "try"), I'm guessing that leaves us with step 3, "replace drive."

Any other ideas for troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Have you tried de-energizing the motor and making sure the pump impeller is free to spin?

Comment: A variable speed drive usually fails in this manor they are usually driven by dual SCR’s with anodes in opposite directions. When the SCR’s fail they normally short out then blow open, if you have a fire down with an electronics background sometimes these can be repaired but many times on these low end ones the boards are damaged and a new controller is needed.